# Alternative derivation of the classical inequality $x^s\le 1+ s(x-1)$ for $0<s<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

The inequality
$$x^s\le 1+ s(x-1)$$
for $x>0$ and any $0<s<1$ is usually proven firstly for rational $s$ using AM-GM, and then by some density of the rationals argument. My question:

*Are there any mistakes in the following alternative derivation?*

For simplicity let's consider the case $s=1/k$, where $k$ is a natural number.

Then the inequality we want to prove, $x^{1/k}<1+(x-1)/k$, is equivalent to
$$ x \le (1+\frac{x-1}{k})^k$$

By the binomial theorem, the RHS is equal to

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(\frac{x-1}{k})^i=1+(x-1)+\sum_{i=2}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(\frac{x-1}{k})^i$$

Plugging this into the former inequality reduces it to proving that

$$\sum_{i=2}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(\frac{x-1}{k})^i\ge0$$

This is obvious for $x\ge1$, so let's consider $0<x<1$. We notice that in this case, when $i$ is even the corrisponding term in the above sum is positive, and when $i$ is odd the term is negative. So if we prove that the sum of two consecutive terms, that is

$$\binom{k}{i}(\frac{x-1}{k})^i+\binom{k}{i+1}(\frac{x-1}{k})^{i+1}\ge0$$

for a certain even $2\le i\le k$, then the sum of every consecutive two terms in the previous sum is positive and so the sum will be positive too.

Simplifying the binomials in the former expression we get:

$$(i+1)(\frac{x-1}{k})^i+(k-i)(\frac{x-1}{k})^{i+1}\ge0$$

and  simplifying the other terms (excluding the case $x=1$), remembering that $x-1<0$, we end up with:

$$(i+1)-(k-i)(\frac{1-x}{k})\ge0$$

which is equivalent to

$$(i+1)\ge(1-i/k)(1-x)$$

On the RHS we have a product of two numbers both less than $1$, and on the LHS an integer $\ge 3$, so the inequality is obvious.

Comment: Is the inequality a $\leq$ ?

Comment: $x\mapsto x^s$ is strictly concave if $0<s<1$. Thus its graph is below the tangent at $x=1$, which is given by $x\mapsto 1+s(x-1)$, and equality only holds in the tangent point $(1,1)\,$.

Comment: @bluebril yes indeed.

Comment: @Hanno there's many ways to derive it I guess. My question was if there's anything wrong with mine above, since I'm not convinced because the last inequality in the proof is so 'trivial' that it seems weird.

Comment: Won't the parity of $k$ matter?

Comment: @bluebril It doesn't: if $k$ is odd then the sum (starting from 2) will have an even number of terms, and successive pairs are positive so the whole sum is. If $k$ is even, then the sum is positive up to the $k-1$ term (which is odd), and the last term is positive because the exponent of $(x-1)$ is $k$ which is even.

Comment: Gotcha! What do you mean by remembering that $0<x-1<0$?

Comment: @bluebril it's a typo, sorry. It's supposed to be $x-1<0$, because in simplifying the inequality we are dividing by $(1-x)$ which is then positive.

Comment: Gotcha! Will then parity of $i$ matter in the simplifying step?

Comment: @bluebril yes it will. for the simplification to work (dividing by $(1-x)^i$) we need $i$ to be even. We in fact are considering only that case because it is sufficient, as it is explained a few lines above (for a certain even $i$ such that $2\le i \le k$)

Comment: Right. I do not see any problem in your proof.